# Browser displays math.stackexchange.com in a completely different way

Tags: support

Today I opened  math.stackexchange.com whit Google Chrome as usual an it looks like completely different:

[image]

If I open it with Internet Explorer it looks like as usual:
[image]

meta.math.stackexchange.com hasn't changed in Google Chrome.

Can somebody tell my what happened? I don't like  this new look and I even don't know how to navigate to my account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To me it seems as if you opened the mobile version. If you are working on a computer, you should be able to click on `full site` at the bottom of the page, to navigate back to the usual view. To navigate from the usual view to the mobile version, you can click on `mobile`, which is also located at the bottom of the page.

Comment: You are right. I remember I tried out some links in the bottom line yesterday. Thx

Comment: I have added (google-chrome) tag, because at first it seemed that it is bug related to chrome. Since you confirmed that this is not about chrome but about displaying a different version of the site, I have removed the tag again.